# Alphabet pyramid method java

Tags: java

I have to write a method that takes no parameters and prints out the alphabet like this:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefghi
abcdefghij
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijkl
abcdefghijklm
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmno
abcdefghijklmnop
abcdefghijklmnopq
abcdefghijklmnopqr
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The code I have so far is as follows :

```
char ch;
for( ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++ )
    System.out.println(ch);
System.out.println("Purple Loop");
```

But i'm unsure as to how i'm supposed to get it in the pyramid formation. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you loop, you can append the current character to a `StringBuilder` and print out the line:

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    line.append(ch);
    System.out.println(line.toString());
}
```

Comment: @CH26 If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
    char ch = 'a';
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++, ch++)
        System.out.print(ch);
    System.out.println();
}
```